# JSON Object nulo

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment, nullpointerexception

soy un programador inexperto que esta desarrollando en Android utilizando el lenguaje Java. Mi problema es que estoy haciendo una request con la libreria Volley y el servidor responde correctamente pero, al momento de parsear la respuesta recibida de un JSON a un JSON Array en una clase no se llena la información y el arreglo queda como nulo. Aquí un fragmento del código

```
    private void getDatosVacantes() {
    String url = "http://10.18.232.64/SNE_API/getDatosVacante.php";

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            System.out.println(response);
            JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonParser().parse(response).getAsJsonArray();

            System.out.println("JSON" + jsonArray);
            JSON.DatosVacante[] vacantesDisponibles = new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray, JSON.DatosVacante[].class);

            String nombre = vacantesDisponibles[0].nomEmpresa;
            String oferta = vacantesDisponibles[0].oferta;

            System.out.println("nombre " + nombre);
            System.out.println("oferta " + oferta);
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            System.out.println("Error del servidor/n" + error);
        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Cabe destacar que se está realizando en un fragmento, de antemano gracias:)

aqui el codigo de error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.sne, PID: 17584
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sne/com.example.sne.PantallaPrincipal}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2907)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2986)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1641)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6694)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:769)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array
    at com.example.sne.fragments.FragmentPrincipal.onCreateView(FragmentPrincipal.java:47)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3273)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3229)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:620)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1355)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7001)
```

Comment: Al Llegar a esta linea System.out.println(response); cual es el string que responde podrías facilitarlo.?

Comment: Con gusto! esto es lo que recibo (disculpa si no sale el codigo con formato, es mi primera pregunta) :

`[{"NombreEmpresa":"Pizza Lalin","TituloOferta":"Busco repartidor de pizzas"},{"NombreEmpresa":"Mh Herramientas","TituloOferta":"Busco operador de herramientas pesadas"},{"NombreEmpresa":"Manisher","TituloOferta":"Solicito ingeniero en metalurgia\r\n"}]`

Comment: @IvánGuzmán cual es la linea 47 de FragmentPrincipal?

Comment: @Elenasys se refiere al momento de ingresar a una lista los datos para mostrarlos en un recycler view:

`ArrayList<itemVacantes> listaVacantes = new ArrayList<>();
        listaVacantes.add(new itemVacantes(R.drawable.ic_person, vacantesDisponibles[0].nomEmpresa, vacantesDisponibles[0].oferta));`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

el Problema esta en la forma que intentas parsear los datos te paso un ejemplo de como puedes obtener los valores de un JSONArray.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        String response = "[  \n"
                + "   {  \n"
                + "      \"NombreEmpresa\":\"Pizza Lalin\",\n"
                + "      \"TituloOferta\":\"Busco repartidor de pizzas\"\n"
                + "   },\n"
                + "   {  \n"
                + "      \"NombreEmpresa\":\"Mh Herramientas\",\n"
                + "      \"TituloOferta\":\"Busco operador de herramientas pesadas\"\n"
                + "   },\n"
                + "   {  \n"
                + "      \"NombreEmpresa\":\"Manisher\",\n"
                + "      \"TituloOferta\":\"Solicito ingeniero en metalurgia\\r\\n\"\n"
                + "   }\n"
                + "]";
        System.out.println(response);

        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

        JSONArray ArrayItems = (JSONArray) jsonParser.parse(response);
        //Print Cuerpo Array            
        System.err.println("ARRAY Print:" + ArrayItems.toJSONString());

        //La Mejor forma es cargando estos Datos en un ArrayList Ejemplo si lo deseas

        ArrayList<vacantesDisponibles> lista=new ArrayList<>();

        //Recorremos el Array

        for (int i = 0; i < ArrayItems.size(); i++) {
            //obtemos los objetos que componen el Array
            JSONObject cuerpo = (JSONObject) ArrayItems.get(i);
            //obtemos los valores.
            String NombreEmpresa=cuerpo.get("NombreEmpresa").toString();
            String TituloOferta=cuerpo.get("TituloOferta").toString();
            vacantesDisponibles objetos=new vacantesDisponibles();
            objetos.setNombreEmpresa(NombreEmpresa);
            objetos.setTituloOferta(TituloOferta);
            //Cargamos el Objecto al ArrayList
            lista.add(objetos);

        }

        ///o bien puedes hacer uso de los valores directamente por el Indice..
        System.err.println("Obteniendo Valores por Indice...");
        JSONObject cuerpo = (JSONObject) ArrayItems.get(0);
        //obtemos los valores.
        String NombreEmpresa=cuerpo.get("NombreEmpresa").toString();
        String TituloOferta=cuerpo.get("TituloOferta").toString();

        System.err.println("NombreEmpresa:"+NombreEmpresa);
        System.err.println("TituloOferta:"+TituloOferta);

    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```